How to implement Mediatr INotification handler as a singleton
Maybe I'm trying to use the wrong tool for the job here and will happily take advice on better ways to implement this project.
I have an application that broadly processes stock market prices, price comes in then component X, Y and Z have to do something with it. Component X may also then require information from Component Y that it has finished processing.
My problem with using INotification handlers is that Mediatr creates a new instance of my handler class even if I've created the handler as Singleton in DI which means any state I've had is lost.
Any ideas on the best way to structure this?
`   public async Task Update_Bars()
{
try
{
while (true)
{
            Console.WriteLine($"ContinueDailyBacktest {ContinueDailyBacktest}");
            if (ContinueDailyBacktest)
            {
                
                //THIS WILL EMIT PRICES UNTIL IT REACHES AN EOD FLAG, OR IT SHOULD
                var data = _priceEmmitter.GetNextItem();
                if (data.EndOfData)
                {
                    this.ContinueBacktest = false;
                    break;
                }

                Bar bar = FuturePrices[data.Ticker][data.Date];


                var notification = new NewPriceNotification(bar);
                notification.Security = (Instrument)TickerList.First(i => i.Ticker == data.Ticker);
                await _mediator.Publish(notification);


                if (data.EndOfDay)
                {
                    Log.Warning("Continuing Daily Backtest stopped");
                    this.ContinueDailyBacktest = false;
                   await _mediator.Publish(new EodEvent(data.Date));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, $"{nameof(Datahandler)}");
    }
}

public async Task Handle(EodCompleteEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    this.ContinueDailyBacktest = true;
    Log.Warning("Continuing Daily Backtest started");
    //return Task.CompletedTask;
}`

My ContinueDailyBacktest is not updated in the original instance thats running when its handled by the "Handle" method
